# OpenCV giving error when trying to convert bitmap to Mat

Tags: android, opencv

I get the erro`No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)` on the lines

```
mat=new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bMap,mat);
```

If I initialize the variable mat in  BaseLoaderCallBack I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mat == null`
How can I solve this, I am using OpenCV 3.2.0, and for some reason I there is no Highgui as well.